# tkinter binding keyRelease works just as keyPress

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter in python 3 to make a primitive game (I am aware of pyGame). My function that I have bound to KeyReleased is executed when any key is pressed. It seems to work just as KeyPress. Code down below

master.bind("KeyRelease",keyReleased) (with <> on the sides of KeyRelease

Answer (score 0):

Most keyboards and OS's will send a steady stream of press/release events when you hold a key down. If you bind to `<KeyRelease>`, it absolutely will only fire on key release but your app may be betting multiple key release events, making it appear that they are happening on a press.